# problem while rendering erb template [ruby]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instance-variables

Im reading an old tutorial about instance variables.

However i wasnt able to call de instance variable from the CONTROLLER to the VIEW.

### The code is:

VIEW :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title> title </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>            line 1       </p>
    <p> <%=       @text   %>    </p>

  </body>  
</html>
```

---

CONTROLLER:

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
  def movies
    @text = "movietitle"
  end
end
```

---

When i load the page, it only shows the line 1 paragraph.

How can i call the instance variable @TEST?

Comment: changed the title because the older sucked

Comment: are you even at the movies/movies page?

Comment: What are the file names and locations you're using?

Comment: Well if he says he sees the line 1 paragraph I assume he is rendering the right file, but its still odd. Could you please copy + paste the html source code that the browser is displaying.

Comment: Make sure that the line @text = "movietitle" gets executed(may be by  putting debugger in the first line of the movies action.

Comment: I havent been able to make the instance variables work.

I am doing the following tutorial and it runs ok.

http://fairleads.blogspot.com/2007/12/rails-20-and-scaffolding-step-by-step.html

but in the end i want to call an instance variable from the CONTROLLER to the VIEW and it doesnt load.

i have uploaded this video if you can help me.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xixCNjcpxUQ

Thanks!

Comment: @daniel

I havent been able to make the instance variables work.

I am doing the following tutorial and it runs ok.

http://fairleads.blogspot.com/2007/12/rails-20-and-scaffolding-step-by-step.html

but in the end i want to call an instance variable from the CONTROLLER to the VIEW and it doesnt load.

i have uploaded this video if you can help me.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xixCNjcpxUQ

Thanks!

Comment: @Arun

I havent been able to make the instance variables work.

I am doing the following tutorial and it runs ok.

http://fairleads.blogspot.com/2007/12/rails-20-and-scaffolding-step-by-step.html

but in the end i want to call an instance variable from the CONTROLLER to the VIEW and it doesnt load.

i have uploaded this video if you can help me.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xixCNjcpxUQ

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok based on your video, here is your problem.
You add a new controller method to movies called newaction. In your browser you go to /movies which effectively, calls the controller method index for movie and renders the index.hmtl.erb for movies. Inside index.html.erb you try to get the variable you declared in newaction, this is another completely different action and of course anything in newaction is not accesible from the index view. 
The biggest problem is you seem to think controller methods are like functions which are called from view, they are not.

1. Read how the MVC model works: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html
2. You have to create a newaction.html.erb view in movies
3. You need to add the newaction action to your routes.rb file

Read this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

The code in routes.rb will look like.

```
resources :movies do
  get 'newaction'
end
```

if you do these and you go to /movies/newaction and inside newaction.html.erb display the title, it will work.

Comment: OK I added the code and a link to a guide that is a definitive read.

Comment: Hi daniel, I do what you said and it return me -> undefined method resources.

I have uploaded this video if you can help me.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PC-OBxri5Jo

Thanks.

Comment: resources was added in rails 3. You are using rails 2. Sorry can't help you with rails 2, you can try googling how rails 2 routes work.

Answer (score 2):

The `@test` variable should contain `"movietitle"`, and it should properly print both paragraphs.

Maybe the extra space (because of pretty printing) is screwing things up? Try:

```
<p>line 1</p>
<p><%=@text%></p>
```

EDIT:

for what you showed, your controller method must be named `index` not `movies`

Comment: Wasn't me but `<%=        @text    %>` and `<%=@text%>` should do exactly the same thing.

Comment: I thought the same thing, but again there's nothing else that rings a bell on what the OP showed :S

Comment: names - location and source.

http://postimage.org/image/1yy93kzt0/

http://postimage.org/image/168pfpqhw/

Comment: Downvote unnecessary, upvoting to correct it. I think the question is unclear from what he has shown. The issue is probably along filenames, his route etc.

Comment: I havent been able to make the instance variables work.

I am doing the following tutorial and it runs ok.

http://fairleads.blogspot.com/2007/12/rails-20-and-scaffolding-step-by-step.html

but in the end i want to call an instance variable from the CONTROLLER to the VIEW and it doesnt load.

i have uploaded this video if you can help me.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xixCNjcpxUQ

Thanks!